# Pandas - get_loc nearest for whole column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a df with date and price.
Given a datetime, I would like to find the price at the nearest date.

This works for one input datetime:

```
import requests, xlrd, openpyxl, datetime
import pandas as pd

file = "E:/prices.csv" #two columns: Timestamp (UNIX epoch), Price (int)
df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None, names=["Timestamp", "Price"])

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'],unit='s')

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Timestamp'], keep='last')
df = df.set_index('Timestamp')

file = "E:/input.csv" #two columns: ID (string), Date (dd-mm-yyy hh:ss:mm)
dfinput = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None, names=["ID", "Date"])
dfinput['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(dfinput['Date'], dayfirst=True)

exampledate = pd.to_datetime("20-3-2020 21:37", dayfirst=True)
exampleprice = df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(exampledate, method='nearest')]["Price"]
print(exampleprice) #price as output
```

I have another dataframe with the datetimes ("dfinput") I want to lookup prices of and save in a new column "Price".
Something like this which is obviously not working:

```
dfinput['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(dfinput['Date'], dayfirst=True)
dfinput['Price'] = df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(dfinput['Date'], method='nearest')]["Price"]
dfinput.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, columns=["Hash", "Date", "Price"])
```

Can I do this for a whole column or do I need to iterate over all rows?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including sample data and what output you want to see as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) (cannot test, because no sample data):

```
df = df.sort_index('Timestamp')
dfinput = dfinput.sort_values('Date')

df = pd.merge_asof(df, dfinput, left_index=True, right_on='Date', direction='nearest')
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed helped me to get the correct output!